# How to display a properly-working favicon for Icecast2/ubuntu web client/site-specific browser/PWAs

Tags: html, xml, favicon, icecast

Icecast 2.4.4 on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS:
I put a favicon.ico in /usr/share/icecast2/web and it shows in the tab bar of Chrome, however it does not show up properly for web-page-as-windows generated by Chrome > More tools > Create shortcut... > Open as window > Create.  In fact, it shows up as a grey box with an "I" in it (short for Icecast2 undoubtedly).  I created a bunch of favicons and some code[1] at [realfavicongenerator.net](https://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_result?file_id=p1gq7ktkdc1u75tie1ie65651vdf6)

[1]: Insert the following code in the  section of your pages:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png">
<link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest">
<link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff"
```

> 

Answer (score 0):

From what I've been able to workout:

1. Get a large file for the favicon you wish to create; e.g., for Icecast2, I used [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f7/Icecast_logo_large_2004.svg/1200px-Icecast_logo_large_2004.svg.png) 1,200 px × 1,360 px .png graphic from wikipedia. (An .svg graphic would be preferable; the site in (2) states, "Submit an image (PNG, JPG, SVG...), at least 70x70. Your image should be 260x260 or more for optimal results.")
2. Create a favicon package at e.g., https://realfavicongenerator.net/ [*]
3. Unzip the favicon package (e.g., favicon_package_v0.16.zip) in `/usr/share/icecast2/web` (*May* work in `/etc/icecast2/web`)
4. sudo nano /etc/icecast2/icecast.xml file to include the following in the <http-headers> section:

   ```
   <header name="icon" value="/usr/share/icecast2/web/favicon.ico" />
   <header name="icon" value="/usr/share/icecast2/web/favicon-32x32.png" />
   <header name="icon" value="/usr/share/icecast2/web/favicon-16x16.png" />
   ```
5. Clear cached images and file from Chrome: [chrome://settings/clearBrowserData] for the icon to update.
6. Create SSB/Open-as-window shortcut: Chrome⋮ > More tools > Create shortcut… > ☑ Open as window.

I don't know what the rest of the RFG code in the OP does and since I have the right favicon working in the chrome tab bar *and* in the chrome SSB shortcut window ***and*** in the OS (Ubuntu 22.10) status bar, I have a functional setup for desktop.

[*]: [RealFaviconGenerator](https://realfavicongenerator.net/) was referenced in this [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59057592/favicon-shows-in-tab-header-but-not-when-create-a-shortcut-by-dragging-from-the%20by%20the%20creator) by the author, [phillippe-b](https://stackoverflow.com/users/499917/philippe-b).

After (in Chrome):
[image: Working favicons on Chrome Icecast SSB]

[NB: the SSB icons for Google Voice & Gmail]

Before (in Chrome and FF):

[image: Non-working favicons in Chrome & FF]